# DataFrame column type changes after filling blank cell with user input value in python

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I have a large excel file uploaded to spyder, just for an eg. I have made it simple -

```
           Date      Name   Project    Age    Pin_code     Remarks    Gender
   0    2020-01-01      a     proj_a    34     123456      grade_a      M
   1    2019-12-04      b     proj_b    48     789012                 
   2                    c               54                              M
```

Now I need to fill blank cells(only string columns) with user input value, suppose user typed - *`'no_entry'`*, then in all the string column I need to fill this value to blank cells, and for numeric column I need to fill `0` and for datetime column I need to fill -  `0000-00-00`. The problem which I am facing is - after insertion, date was initially appears like - `2020-01-01` after insertion it becomes - `2020-01-01 00:00:00` and also it assigns only 0 to blank cell, pin_code column becomes float like - `789012.0`. How to avoid these obstruction, please help.

my code -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_dtype

ip = input('Please enter a value for blank cells : ')
col = df.columns
for c in col:
    if is_string_dtype(df[c]) == True:
        df[c].fillna(ip, inplace = True)
    if is_integer_dtype(df[c]) == True :
        df[c].fillna(0, inplace = True)
    if is_datetime64_dtype(df[c]) == True:  
        df[c].fillna(0000-00-00, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need not valid pandas datetime - `0000-00-00` is necessary convert dates to strings and for convert numeric to integers use `astype(int)`

```
ip = input('Please enter a value for blank cells : ')

for c in  df.columns:
    if is_string_dtype(df[c]):
        df[c].fillna(ip, inplace = True)
    if is_numeric_dtype(df[c]):
        df[c] = df[c].fillna(0).astype(int)
    if is_datetime64_dtype(df[c]):  
        df[c] = df[c].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').fillna('0000-00-00')
```

Comment: thank you Sir for this help, just one thing, in the later part I need to filter the dataframe on the basis of numeric column and datetime column, but i am unable to catch date colu,mn as it becomes an object now, and for one or two column I can type conversion is possible but for 1000 columns it is not possible, any suggestion?

Comment: @KReEd - It is problem, because `00:00:00` datetime in pandas not exist. Is possible use e.g. `1970-01-01` instead?

Comment: @KReEd - then is changed `df[c] = df[c].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').fillna('0000-00-00')` to `df[c] = df[c].fillna(pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01'))`